# How to use KerasClassifier validation split and using scitkit learn GridSearchCV

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, data-science, tf.keras

I want to try to test some hyperparameters, thats i want to use the GridSearchCV, because it seems like thats the way to do it.

But i also want to use the validation split. To use Callsbacks like EarlyStopping or/and ReduceLROnPlateau. So my question is:
How do i implement GridSearchCV + validation_split correctly that none of the data in validation split is using for training and the whole training set is used to train my model? 
Afaik GridSearchCV split again my remaining train data (which is 1-validation_split) and split it again? I get kinda high accuracy and im thinking that i dont split the data correctly

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model,verbose=2, validation_split=0.1)
optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
init = ['glorot_uniform',
        #'normal',
        'uniform',
        'he_normal',
        #'lecun_normal',
        #'he_uniform'
       ]
epochs = [3] #5,8,10,30
batches = [64] #32,64
param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizers, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches, init=init)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your self-defined validation data by passing an extra argument to the `grid.fit()` function that is `validation_data=(X_test, Y_test)`. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasClassifier#fit), states that `grid.fit()` function accepts all valid arguments that can be passed to the actual `model.fit()` function of the default Keras [model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). Therefore, you can pass the validation data through the `grid.fit()` function. You may also pass the callback functions there.

I am adding a working code below (applied on MNIST-digit dataset). Notice how I added the validation data on `grid.fit()` and removed the 'validation_split':

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist 
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, 10)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, 10)
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, 3)
X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, 3)

def create_model(optimizer, init):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
         tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(32, 3, input_shape=(28, 28, 1), 
                                       activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init),
         tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(32, 3, activation='relu',
                                       kernel_initializer=init),
         tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu', 
                               kernel_initializer=init),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', 
                               kernel_initializer=init),
    ])
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=2,)
optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
init = ['glorot_uniform',
        #'normal',
        'uniform',
        'he_normal',
        #'lecun_normal',
        #'he_uniform'
       ]
epochs = [4,] 
batches = [32, 64] 
param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizers, nb_epoch=epochs, 
                  batch_size=batches, init=init)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.